# Why is my data insertion in my Cassandra database sometimes stable and sometimes slow?

Tags: python, cassandra, scrapy, apache-kafka

This is my query if the current data ID is present or absent in the Cassandra database:

```python
row = session.execute("SELECT * FROM articles where id = %s", [id])
```

Resolved messages in Kafka, then determine whether or not this message exists in the Cassandra database if it does not exist, then it should perform an insert operation, if it does exist, it should not be inserted in the data.

```python
messages = consumer.get_messages(count=25)

if len(messages) == 0:
    print 'IDLE'
    sleep(1)
    continue

for message in messages:
    try:
        message = json.loads(message.message.value)
        data = message['data']
        if data:
            for article in data:
                source = article['source']
                id = article['id']
                title = article['title']
                thumbnail = article['thumbnail']
                #url = article['url']
                text = article['text']
                print article['created_at'],type(article['created_at'])
                created_at = parse(article['created_at'])
                last_crawled = article['last_crawled']
                channel = article['channel']#userid
                category = article['category']
                #scheduled_for = created_at.replace(minute=created_at.minute + 5, second=0, microsecond=0)
                scheduled_for=(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=5)).replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
                row = session.execute("SELECT * FROM articles where id = %s", [id])
                if len(list(row))==0:
                #id parse base62
                    ids = [id[0:2],id[2:9],id[9:16]]
                    idstr=''
                    for argv in ids:
                        num = int(argv)
                        idstr=idstr+encode(num)
                    url='http://weibo.com/%s/%s?type=comment' % (channel,idstr)
                    session.execute("INSERT INTO articles(source, id, title,thumbnail, url, text, created_at, last_crawled,channel,category) VALUES (%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (source, id, title,thumbnail, url, text, created_at, scheduled_for,channel,category))
                    session.execute("INSERT INTO schedules(source,type,scheduled_for,id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s) USING TTL 86400", (source,'article', scheduled_for, id))
                    log.info('%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (source, id, title,thumbnail, url, text, created_at, scheduled_for,channel,category))

    except Exception, e:
        log.exception(e)
        #log.info('error %s %s' % (message['url'],body))
        print e
        continue
```

I have one ID which only has one unique table row, which I want to be like this. As soon as I add different scheduled_for times for the unique ID my system crashes. Add this `if len(list(row))==0:` is the right thought but my system is very slow after that.

This is my table description:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schedules;

CREATE TABLE schedules (
 source text,
 type text,
 scheduled_for timestamp,
 id text,
 PRIMARY KEY (source, type, scheduled_for, id)
);
```

This scheduled_for is changeable. Here is also a concrete example:

```
Hao article 2016-01-12 02:09:00+0800 3930462206848285
Hao article 2016-01-12 03:09:00+0801 3930462206848285
Hao article 2016-01-12 04:09:00+0802 3930462206848285
Hao article 2016-01-12 05:09:00+0803 3930462206848285
```

Here is my article CQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE crawler.articles (
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    id text,
    category text,
    channel text,
    last_crawled timestamp,
    text text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY (source, created_at, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC, id ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'sstable_size_in_mb': '160', 'enabled': 'true', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'false', 'tombstone_compaction_interval': '86400', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.2', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 604800
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

CREATE INDEX articles_id_idx ON crawler.articles (id);
CREATE INDEX articles_url_idx ON crawler.articles (url);
```

Comment: Can you provide your table schema for articles? That way we can see primary keys and all details.

Comment: I added the articles scheme in the post above. thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your SCHEMA and the way you use it I could assume that secondary index on ID field is creating problems and slowing down queries. You can check more details why secondary indexes are bad on many places just googling it (this [source](https://pantheon.io/blog/cassandra-scale-problem-secondary-indexes) is a good start, also [DataStax documentation page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html)). Basically when you use secondary index in 5 node cluster you must hit each node to find item you are looking for and when using primary key each node knows which node holds data.

Secondary indexes are particularly bad if you use data with high cardinality (performance drops when you add more items) and you use ID which is different for each article. They are ok when you use low cardinality such as index some data by days of week (you knwo there will be only 7 days in a week so you can predict size of index table) or category in your case if you have finite number of categories.

I would advice to create one more table, `article_by_id` which will be reverse index to your article table. You can use [Lightweight Transaction](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) and do `INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS` first to that table and if operation returns `true` (meaning insert went through so record was not present previously) you can do regular INSERT to your `articles` table and if it return `false` (meaning data was not inserted because it already exists) you can skip INSERT to `articles` table.

Here is table (I would suggest to use UUID instead of text for ID but I created table based on your article table):

```
CREATE TABLE article_by_id (
    id text,
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH comment = 'Article by id.';
```

This way you can always find all parts of your key based on just ID. If ID is your input parameter selecting from this table will give you source and created_at.

Here is insert query which will return true or false:

```
INSERT INTO article_by_id(id, source, created_at) VALUES (%s,%s, %s) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

And more tip, if you can find key based on some non changeable data in your entity than you do not need second table. In example if source and created_at uniquely identifies article in your system and never change you can remove id and use your original table.

Comment: Great answer thanks. what do you think is the best primary key for articles?

Comment: You can leave it as is in articles table (PK source and then clustered by created_at and id on the end to ensure uniqueness). This table is great for range queries and you are spreading data from multiple sources across multiple partitions preventing long rows and hot data. I am just suggesting to have additional table with ID to find it easier. Otherwise you can probably omit ID altogether if URL is unique per article, and use URL instead of ID. Then change ID to URL on all places.

Comment: also another question maybe you can help: if we have table structure below, how can i query by "source = 'abc' and created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'"? This is a problem now since cassandra does not allow to query non index fields.

CREATE TABLE articles (
    id text,
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    category text,
    channel text,
    last_crawled timestamp,
    text text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: Go with two tables, leave your table as is and add another table which will serve only to check if your article exists. Data duplication in Cassandra is common thing and right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks your answers help a lot. Regarding the above mentioned tables: Could you give me 2 CQL statements? would really help me a lot.

Comment: Thanks again really helpful. I also need to query article_by_id by "source ='abc' AND type='article' AND scheduled_for <= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'"
how to achieve this? Still don't quite understand. thanks

Comment: This is single purpose table where you get article ONLY by id, for other queries you can use your existing table where you query by source, type scheduled for range etc. Might be good idea to check free course on data modeling and thing will be clear (https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling) or move this to another question related on modeling alone since our discussion in comments is already too long

Comment: ok thanks for all your help. I move it here in case you have more suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763277/how-to-model-cassandra-in-this-particular-situations?noredirect=1#comment57282627_34763277