# How to model cassandra in this particular situations?

Tags: cassandra

if I have table structure below, how can i query by

```
"source = 'abc' and created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'"?

CREATE TABLE articles (
    id text,
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    category text,
    channel text,
    last_crawled timestamp,
    text text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I would like to model my system according to this:
http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

Edit:

What we are doing is very similar to what you are proposing. The difference is our primary key doesn't have brackets around source: 
`PRIMARY KEY (source, created_at, id)`. We also have two other indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX articles_id_idx ON crawler.articles (id); 
CREATE INDEX articles_url_idx ON crawler.articles (url);
```

Our system is really slow like this. What do you suggest?

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: That still depends on how many distinct values source can have and how many records will be inserted.

Comment: No offense to Jay Patel; that article was *great* for its time, and helped set the foundation for educating devs on proper Cassandra data modeling.  But it is almost 4 years old, and not as relevant as it once was (Cassandra has changed *a lot* in that time).

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the reply I added an edit to our post would be great if you could suggest something since the solution you proposed underneath is similar to what we do now but our system is still very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id text,
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    category text,
    channel text,
    last_crawled timestamp,
    text text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((source),created_at, id)
)
```

You can issue the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE source=xxx // Give me all article given the source xxx

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE source=xxx AND created_at > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'; // Give me all articles whose source is xxx and created after 2016-01-01 00:00:00
```

The couple (created_at,id) in the primary key is here to guarantee article unicity. Indeed, it is possible to have, at the same created_at time, 2 different articles

Comment: Good answer!  This model will also support a range query on `created_at` such as: `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE source='abc' AND created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND ' created_at < '2016-01-05 00:00:00';`

Comment: @doanduyhai What we are doing is very similar to what you are proposing. The difference is our primary key doesn't have brackets around source:  PRIMARY KEY (source, created_at, id).  We also have two other indexes: CREATE INDEX articles_id_idx ON crawler.articles (id);
CREATE INDEX articles_url_idx ON crawler.articles (url); Our system is really slow like this. What do you suggest?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (source, created_at, id) and PRIMARY KEY ((source),created_at, id) are strictly equivalent. The extra parens around source is there to highlight the fact that source is the partition key, no worry.

Comment: "CREATE INDEX articles_id_idx ON crawler.articles (id);" --> Bad usage of secondary index. You'll have at most 1 article for each articles_id_idx. This index will not scale with your cluster size. Same remark for articles_url_idx. I suggest to create either 2 extra denormalization tables article_by_id & article_by_url OR use the new **materialized view** feature of Cassandra 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Given the knowledge from [previous question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760379/why-is-my-data-insertion-in-my-cassandra-database-sometimes-stable-and-sometimes) where I said index is slowing down your query you need to solve two things:

1. Write article only if it does not already exist
2. Query article based on source and range query on created at

Based on those two I would go with two tables:

**Reverse index table**

```
CREATE TABLE article_by_id (
    id text,
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id) ) WITH comment = 'Article by id.';
```

This table will be used to insert articles when they first arrive. Based on return statement after `INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS` you will know if article is existing or new and if it is new you will write to second table. Also this table can serve to find all key parts for second table based on article id. If you need full article data you can add to this table as well all fields (category, channel etc.). This will be skinny row holding only single article in one partition.

Example of INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO article_by_id(id, source, created_at) VALUES (%s,%s, %s) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

Java driver returns true or false whether this query was applied or not. Probably it is same in python driver but I did not use it.

**Table for range queries and queries by source**

As [doanduyhai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873530/doanduyhai) suggested you create a second table:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id text,
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    category text,
    channel text,
    last_crawled timestamp,
    text text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((source),created_at, id)
)
```

In this table you will write only if first INSERT returned true meaning you have new article, not existing one. This table will serve range queries and queries by source.

**Improvement suggestion**

By using `timeuuid` instead of `timestamp` for `created_at` you are sure no two article can have same created_at and you can loose `id` all together and rely on `timeuuid`. However from second question I can see you rely on external id so wanted to mention this as a sidenote.